# Cycle css backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey, I'm just wondering how to cycle through a bunch of images, and set them as the background for a div.

What I'm looking to do is: set the first image as the background to a div. Wait X seconds. Set the next image as the background. Wait X seconds … etc. and continue

I've got the following code which works for 1 image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var source = $(".field-field-background img:first").attr("src");
  $('.field-field-background img:first').remove();
  $('#main-inner').css('background', 'url('+ source +') no-repeat');
});
```

I'm guessing I need to get an array of the image sources, loop through the array and set it as the background, with a delay somewhere in the loop. Any ideas how I'd do this?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel ;) http://buildinternet.com/live/supersized/

Comment: There is a cycle plugin that does something very similar, not sure if it will help you.  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: BackgroundCycle.js along with GSAP helped me create this.  http://jimslounge.com/free_stuff/?fbclid=IwAR3mCppj-PjSq4NFwrpFOYFgmNil0tt90b_Yy8fs1HAQ0A6Xb0J3q2oaVxg

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest advantages of jQuery is that it has a [very robust plug-in community](http://plugins.jquery.com/).  Many tasks that you might want to accomplished have been tackled by others before you.  Particularly with a common task like this, I would recommend looking for a plug-in first, before trying to reinvent the wheel.  Many plug-ins have the advantage of having gone through rigorous testing and multiple versions, to result in a polished product.

The [jQuery Cycle plug-in](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) would be a good candidate, if you are looking to do a slideshow type effect.  If what you want is to cycle the background, while keeping foreground elements, you might look at something more like this: [Advanced jQuery background image slideshow](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Cycler={};
  Cycler.src=['path/to/img1', 'path/to/img2', 'path/to/img3'];
  Cycler.cur=0;
  Cycler.cycle=function() {
    if(++Cycler.cur>=Cycler.src.length) {
      Cycler.cur=0;
    }

    $('#main-inner').css('background', 'url('+ Cycler.src[Cycler.cur] +') no-repeat');
    setTimeout(Cycler.cycle, 5000);//5 seconds
  }

  Cycler.cycle();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, `Cylcler` is a namespace (or an ad-hoc object if you want to call it so) I made to gather all those related things, I just forgot to introduce first with `Cycler={};`. Now fixed.

Comment: I love your approach than other solutions. It'd be great if you could add in fadeIn and fadeOut transition effect code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var source = $(".field-field-background img:first").attr("src");
    $('.field-field-background img:first').remove();
    $('#main-inner').css('background', 'url('+ source +') no-repeat');
},4000);
```