# How can I set fadein and fadeout sildeshow of images in JQuery continusly without any event?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slideshow

How can I set simple JQuery slideshow with CSS continuously, without any event like mouse hover, click etc.?

Answer (score 0):

write a function that does a slidehsow. use `settimeout` give it an interval and call your function.

see an example here: [Cycle css backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636859/cycle-css-backgrounds/3636917#3636917)

Answer (score 0):

Most functions like that in jQuery are called, or at least initialized, in the `$(document).ready()` call. Simply include a timing command like `setInterval` that returns your function and it will run when the DOM is loaded, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = setInterval(mySlideShow, 3000)
    });
```

Or, if the function repeats itself, simply invoke the function on `ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mySlideShow();
    });
```

Edit:

As requested, the simplest slideshow I can think of is something like this:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:images should be set to `display:none`

Then jQuery:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $('#slideshow img:first-child').addClass('shown').show();
>     setInterval(slideShow,3000);
> });
> //and here is the function
> function slideShow()
>     {
>     $('#slideshow img:last-child').prependTo($('#slideshow')).fadeIn(1000);
>     $('.shown').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('shown');
>     }
> ```

Might not be perfect for you but you can see where I'm going with it at least...

Comment: Have you tried [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/)? I think that's a great slideshow and all you need is a `<div>` with some `<img>` tags in it.

Comment: thanks buddy....the images in div should be atabsolute position or not..???? Absolute position needed or not..

Comment: For this example it doesn't matter. If you like my answer- accept it! :)